# identificar y dividir una cadena

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me pidieron un trabajo en winForms en un textbox se ingresara una cadena como 2x+x+5x+9
donde el carácter solo (x) vale 1 y el numero (9) vale 0 y entonces reimprimir la cadena 2x+1+5x+0

estoy intentado usar método string.split para que lo divida por cada + pero no se como indicarle lo del valor de numero y el carácter.

espero  me haya explicado bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        string tarea = textBox1.Text;
        string[] separador = tarea.Split('+');
        foreach(string i in separador)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
        }
```

[image: introducir el código aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso un trozo de código de aplicación de consola que creo que podrás usar en tu código con windows form. La parte que te puede ayudar es la del foreach.

```
        String ejemplo = "2x+3+E";
        ejemplo = ejemplo.Replace(" ", "");
        Char[] caracteresSeparadores = { '+', '-', '*', '/'};
        String[] expresiónSegmentada = ejemplo.Split(caracteresSeparadores, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<String> listaEjemploSimilarAlListBox1 = new List<String>();
        foreach (String item in expresiónSegmentada)
        {
            if (item.Contains('x') && item.Length > 1)
            {
                listaEjemploSimilarAlListBox1.Add(item);
            }
            else if (item.Contains('x') && item.Length == 1)
            {
                listaEjemploSimilarAlListBox1.Add("1"); //Este paso sería siguiendo tu primer comentario. No haría falta este paso si sigo los pasos que indicas en tu último comentario. Podrías quitar este else if y dejar el últimodirectamente.
            }
            else if (!item.Contains('x'))
            {
                try
                {
                    int número = Convert.ToInt32(item);
                    listaEjemploSimilarAlListBox1.Add("0");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    listaEjemploSimilarAlListBox1.Add("1");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Lo siento mira por el momento llevo esto

 string tarea = textBox1.Text;
            string[] separador = tarea.Split('+');
            foreach(string i in separador)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
Lo puse en un listbox para que se puede ver la separación

 y ahora falta que si en la cadena después del + hay un carácter pues lo cambie a 1 o si es un numero 0

Comment: Edito mi primer comentario.